# How to GET html file as object?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I try to get html files as object instead SWF files but I really can't figure out. Have anyone any idea how to do it? This is my request function:

```
function loadFolderStructure( strPath, $currentSelectItem ) {
    if ( 'undefined' === typeof(fsStructure[strPath]) ) {
        $.ajax({
            'url'       : '../php/navigator.php',
            'dataType'  : 'json',
            'data'      : {'tarFolder':strPath},

            success : function( respObj, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
                if ( 'undefined' !== typeof(respObj['status']) ) {
                    if ( 
                            ('success' === respObj['status']) && 
                            ('undefined' !== typeof(respObj['subfolders'])) && 
                            ('undefined' !== typeof(respObj['subswfs'])) ) {

                        processNewDFData( respObj, $currentSelectItem, strPath );
                    } else {
                        alert( conf.messages.bad_response_format );
                    }
                } else {
                    alert( conf.messages.bad_response_format );
                }
            },
            error : function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                alert( conf.messages.failed_ajax_request );
            }
        });
    } else {
        rendSelects( $currentSelectItem, strPath );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't exactly understand what you're asking for, but if you want to get the HTML page as an object you could try:

```
    var x = document.documentElement
```

Comment: To be more specified, This code is looking in a folder as ././data/ there are subfolders and inside them you can find SWF files and HTML files. But instead targeting SWF files I want to target HTML files

Comment: I'm sorry then, I can't help you.